# Zend oauth scopes for google profile

Tags: zend-framework, oauth

Can some one please tell me what would i give as scope for getting the profile picture of a google user  account using zend oauth php

```
require_once 'Zend/Oauth/Consumer.php';
        $SCOPES = array(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email',
            'https://mail.google.com/',
            'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/',
            'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/'
        );
```

while i  give https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#profile, it is throwing error

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The correct names for the `userinfo` scopes are:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

I think the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/) provides the most complete overview of Google OAuth scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Try a period instead of a pound sign. I am successfully able to authenticate https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile at the OAuth 1 playground at http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/. If that doesn't work, compare your requests to the equivalent ones in the playground.